# Change Rails controller name

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's say I have a controller and model called Car/Cars in Rails. Then I wanna change it to Vehicle/Vehicles. How to I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need change the name of file, the name of director and in last, the name of Class.

Comment: Probably want to run a migration to change the name of the table as well.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there's any sort of automated process in Rails to do this. It boils down to a lot of find/replace for your instances of `Car` with `Vehicle` and `cars` with `vehicles`, as well as in all filenames, routes, and the database.

Answer (score 0):

Things to take care of when changing controller name

- **Controller name** and optionally **directory name**
- Controller **class name** in `class XxxController < ApplicationController`
- Associated **routes** in `routes.rb`
- `*_path` and `*_url` `URL helper` instances

Answer (score 0):

To install:
gem install rails_refactor

Before use, make sure you cd to the root of your rails project.

To rename a controller:

> rails_refactor rename OldController NewController

```
renames controller file & class name in file
renames controller spec file & class name in file
renames view directory
renames helper file & module name in file
updates routes
```

To rename a controller action:

> $ rails_refactor rename DummyController.old_action new_action

```
renames controller action in controller class file
renames view files for all formats
```

To rename a model:

> $ rails_refactor rename OldModel NewModel

````
renames model file & class name in file
renames spec file & class name in file
renames migration & class name & table names in file```
````